# PHPUnit how to mock or change the value of a class constant

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I've got a class that has a constant that is accessed by various methods in the class. It has been a constant for long time (legacy code) and we don't wanna change it to be a regular var so I'm stuck with it.

```
const SCHEMA_REPO = [
         "MailNotice" => MailNotice::class,
    ];
```

Now I'm trying to write a test for a method that access this const. But I don't want to use any of the values of the array, I wanna use test values, so I was wondering whether I can change the value of `SCHEMA_REPO` in my test. For instance, I want `SCHEMA_REPO` to be:

```
const SCHEMA_REPO = [
         "TestNoticeA" => "TestNoticeA",
         "TestNoticeB" => "TestNoticeB",
    ];
```

I'm using PHPUnit and Mockery. There's something in the mockery docs called Constant Maps (https://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/cookbook/class_constants.html#constants-map) that are supposed to allow you change the value of a const in a class for tests but it is not working. I have in my test:

```
\Mockery::getConfiguration()->setConstantsMap([
    Repo::class => [
        'SCHEMA_REPO' => [
             'TestNoticeA' => 'TestNoticeA',
             'TestNoticeB' => 'TestNoticeB'
        ],
    ]
]);

$mock = \Mockery::mock(Repo::class);
var_dump($mock::SCHEMA_REPO); // should be ['TestNoticeA' => 'TestNoticeA']
```

when I print `$mock::SCHEMA_REPO` I was expecting to see `['TestNoticeA' => 'TestNoticeA']` but I'm seeing the actual value of `SCHEMA_REPO`:

```
[
         "MailNotice" => MailNotice::class
   ]
```

Am I doing something wrong? or that is not what constants maps are supposed to be used for?

Is there a way to achieve what I'm asking?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**You should test function not class**, I will explain what I mean

let's assume that you have a requirement to do a function to get double the amount of any given number

the testing gonna be like this

```
public function testMyFunction(int $inputNumber): void
{
    assertEqual(2 * $inputNumber, myFunction($inputNumber));
}
```

now you can do the implementation like this:

```
class MyClass {

    public function myFunction($inputNumber): int
    {
        return $inputNumber * 2;
    }
}
```

but you can also do:

```
class MyClass {

    const MULTIPLY_AMOUNT = 2;

    public function myFunction($inputNumber): int
    {
        return $inputNumber * self::MULTIPLY_AMOUNT;
    }
}
```

this is also fine, now the case is you cannot make the MULTIPLY_AMOUNT as a fixture ( you shouldn't consider it as input and test cases), and if you try to pass different values to make sure that the testing will pass,
whenever you change the value of MULTIPLY_AMOUNT you are changing functionality and it is normal behavior to fail because this is not getting double the amount anymore

you should depend on the values of the constant because it is part of the functionality, and if the constant value changes are not changing the functionality then this is not constant but configuration

I hope this to be helpful

Comment: Abdul, sorry, my bad. I made an error while typing the question. I've updated the question. Basically I had exactly what you pointed out in the first part of your comment, yet the value of the class constant is printed out instead of the one I attempted to overwrite. If possible, I'd like to be able to do overwrite the constant just for the test, as I mentioned in the question, we don't want to actually touch the code even with a simple change

Comment: I have also updated the value for you, I hope this is helpful, you may not like it but I don't see it correct to even think about mocking constant, good luck